# Animate margin change

Tags: android, android-animation

I use this code for animate view in android its work perfect
problem when I set margin to zero or margin less the current margin its doesn't animate

the code

```
          int margin = 100;


            ValueAnimator varl = ValueAnimator.ofInt(margin);
            varl.setDuration(200);
            varl.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.setMargins((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue(), 0, 0, 0);
                    myView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
            });
            varl.start();
```

Now when I set margin to 100 it animates, but when I want to set it to zero its set margin without animation

```
 int margin = 0;



            ValueAnimator varl = ValueAnimator.ofInt(margin);
            varl.setDuration(200);
            varl.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.setMargins((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue(), 0, 0, 0);
                    myView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
            });
            varl.start();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't use the `ValueAnimator.ofInt(int... values);` correctly: you should explicitly tell the animator **from** which **to** which value it should animate. So, for example, you should animate from the current value to the wanted value. If your previous value, was, for example, *50*, then the statement should be like this:

`ValueAnimator varl = ValueAnimator.ofInt(50, margin);`

Comment: @medo Okay, you can mark the answer as "accepted", so that we know that this question is solved. I'm glad I was able to help you.

Comment: sure i just wait for finish the 5 minute and i marked it

Answer (score 4):

You can use my [library](https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator) for that:

```
ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.animate(myView).leftMargin(100).setDuration(200).start();
```

Comment: YOU'RE AN ABSOLUTE LIFESAVER! THANKS!